# Area51 not in top 5 SE sites

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, area-51, top-bar

[Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is in the list of SE sites of the new top-bar included.

But since [I have 700 rep there](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/46349/juergen-d) it should be in my top 5 sites to be consistent.

[image: top-bar]

<sub>BTW I don't get notified about new rep on Area51 as well.</sub>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Area 51 is different and does not aggregate in the same way as all other code bases which makes it prohibitively expensive to load in the site switcher.  The other totals we've gotten data aggregated to the point it's a single efficient query when not cached (also keep in mind it has to be re-fetched on the first hit after your reputation changes on any site).

We preload this section of the dropdown *in the original page*, so performance is absolutely critical here, it affects **every logged in page load**.

We aren't prepared to aggregate Area 51 at this time, or likely ever.  It's a different code base that serves a different purpose (it's not Q&A) which would mean some schema changes to the network tables with contain homogeneously aggregated data.

So basically: if it were cheap we'd show it...but it's not and it's an very non-trivial amount of work to make it so (it has *none* of the aggregation system) or keep it current.

Comment: So you don't do it because the database design is bad? Why don't you just fix the database?

Comment: @MrLore I'm going to pretend that was a satirical question, since "fixing" the database involves bringing Area 51 up to date with code in core which is over 3 years apart now.

Comment: @MrLore it's not about good or bad, it's about spending lots of efforts on something not worth it. Better spend this time on developing awesome new things (e.g. winterbash ;)) or fixing more important bugs.

Comment: Isn't a user's rep on Area 51 Discussion the same as their rep on Area 51? Considering Discussion rep is shown in "Your Communities", why not just show Discussion's rep next to the Area 51 link?