# MultiCollider / Site Switcher not showing all sites that I have accounts on

Tags: support, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

When looking at the MultiCollider drop down I'm not seeing my accounts on Code Review or Area 51.

[image]

I could swear I saw my Code Review account there the day I created the account, but since then it seems to be missing.

The [only reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198613/feedback-request-new-top-bar-and-multicollider-redesign) I could find on the intended behavior of the MultiCollider:

> Your current site appears at the top, along with any relevant meta, chat, and blog links. Stack Overflow gets a careers 2.0 link.
>   Immediately below, in a new condensed format (you certainly don’t need
>   descriptions if you’re participating in a site already), **you’ll get
>   a list of all the sites that you have logged into, in order of
>   reputation.** Finally, you’ll find the full alphabetical site list
>   with descriptions, searchable by title, URL, and description.

Comment: Your rep on Code Review went down below 100 so you won't see it anymore until it's back to 101. (same score items are sorted alphabetically)

Comment: @ShadowWizard that makes sense for Code Review, but what about Area 51? I think my rep there is 206.

Comment: Area51 does not show in the site list of the top bar, it's a known issue and by design. (going to look where it was mentioned)

Comment: [Found it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211253/152859).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site selector only shows a limited selection of sites that you're most active (read: have most rep) on at the top above the search bar.  For example, mine currently looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of Stack Exchange site switcher drop-down menu]

The rest of [the 63 sites I have an account on](https://stackexchange.com/users/178805/ilmari-karonen?tab=accounts) don't get shown at the top — if I want to get to them via the sitw switcher menu, I have to look for them in the alphabetical list (or use the search box).

As for *why* this is done, well, let's go back to that **"63 sites"** part.  Sure, I might appreciate a convenient link to [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/3239/), [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/4646/), [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/239/) or [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/496/), all of which I have more than 1k rep on, but if those were *all* included at the top of the menu, **the search box would drop out of sight** — and that would be a much bigger inconvenience.  And I'd *still* be missing out on several sites that I visit pretty often, but don't happen to have as much rep on.

<sup>A simple "show more..." link above the search box *would* be kind of nice to have, though.</sup>

And if you think *I* have it bad, just think of all the poor SE employees who have an account on *all* the sites...