# Why does Area 51 not show up in the 'your communities' section?

Tags: bug, area-51, communities-list

I like to quickly jump from one StackExchange site to another using the 'your communities' section in the StackExchange dropdown menu, but my Area 51 account isn't listed over there. Why's that?[image: (picture)]

(i've marked this with the tag 'bug' because i don't know why it isn't there...)

Comment: oops indeed, didn't find that question. @PeterJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not added automatically, as the dropdown [doesn't load your reputation from Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211253/222623), but you can add it yourself using the edit link so that you can navigate there from your communities list.

Click edit (to the right of the Your Communities title), filter for Area 51 and click Add, then refresh. The edit link also lets you sort the list manually by dragging, so you can place Area 51 where it should be according to reputation.