# Show Area 51 rep with Area 51 Discussions rep

Tags: feature-request, reputation, area-51, communities-list

A while ago Nick Craver [explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211253/341085) why Area 51 reputation isn't shown in "Your Communities". However, Area 51 Discussions' reputation shows up:

[image]

Since Discussions' reputation is equal to Area 51's, why not just show Discussion's rep next to the Area 51 link?

Comment: How did you add it to the list?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I clicked "edit" next to "Your Communities". You can actually search for meta sites. In the search bar, I typed in "Area 51 Discussions" and added it.

Comment: hmm... good point lol. Well, agree it makes sense to do that then.