# Top bar bug - no reputation shown for Area 51

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, area-51, top-bar

The top bar's hamburger menu displays all the community's you're a member of, and your reputation there.

Area 51  is displayed there, but its reputation isn't. Funnily enough, Area 51 Discussion Zone (the Area 15 meta site) is also displayed there, with the shadow reputation from Area 51:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Even more curious is the fact that even Area 51's (outdated) top bar doesn't display this reputation:

[image]

Comment: I don't *know* exactly why this is, but I'm guessing it probably has something to do with the fact that you have to log in to Area51 separately from your SE login.

Comment: @anonymous2 I don't think so. I'm logged in to Area 51, and even in Area 51 itself the rep isn't displayed in the top bar - see my edited question.

Comment: We don't aggregate data from Area 51 and haven't for a long time: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209470/area51-not-in-top-5-se-sites